# How to perform click on element (button) that contains X title?

Tags: javascript, getelementsbyclassname

I am trying to click on the button class "btn ActionBar__button", but there are 2 of them and it always clicks on the button that contains the title "Don't Click".

How can I click on the button with the same class, but has a different title?

I am trying to use this code:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('btn ActionBar__button'); elems[0].click();
```

Here is the HTML:

```html
<div class="ActionBar">

<button class="btn ActionBar__button" type="button" title="Don't Click">Don't Click</button>

<button class="btn ActionBar__button" type="button" title="Click on this button">Click on this button</button></div>
```

Comment: Well you are always clicking on index 0, which is the first button. if you want to click on the second button, then you need to do index 1 with `elems[1].click();`

Comment: There is nothing in this question regarding C# or Chrome Embedded. Please use only tags that are relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **.querySelector**

```js
let elem = document.querySelector('[title="Click on this button"]');

console.log(elem)

elem.click();
```

```html
<div class="ActionBar">

    <button class="btn ActionBar__button" type="button" title="Don't Click">Don't Click</button>

    <button class="btn ActionBar__button" type="button" title="Click on this button">Click on this button</button></div>
```